# Mensagem de alerta no JavaScript não funciona

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando criar uma mensagem de alerta no meu site utilizando o comando window.alert, porém esta mensagem de alerta não aparece, nem ao menos no codigo-fonte dos navegadores aparece o comando que digitei.Este é o código ao qual me refiro:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>meu primeiro programa...</title><!--ISSO É UM COMENTARIO em html..-->
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: rgb(95, 95, 180);
            color: white; /* Comentario em CSS*/
            font: normal 25pt arial;
        }
        h1 {
            color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.589) ; 
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>revendedora autorizada ferreira</h1>
    <p> tudo para seu automóvel novo e semi-novo.</p>
    <script>
        var n1 = Number.parseInt(window.prompt(`digite um número: `))
        var n2 = Number.parseInt(window.prompt(`digite outro número:`))
        var s = n1 + n2
        window.alert(`a soma dos valores é :` + s)
        //(number + number) + para adição
        // (string + string)+ para concatenação
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Como falei, a linha do window.alert não aparece, não sei porque o motivo.
desde já, agradeço.

Comment: Tem que colocar o texto do alert entre aspas. E do prompt tb.

Comment: eu coloquei entre aspas, dai eu sabia que poderia ser um erro por não ter colocado entre crases, mas mesmo assim da o mesmo problema, não roda no meu navegador.

Comment: já foram colocadas as aspas em todos, mesmo assim, sem efeito.

Comment: está usando as aspas erradas para este contexto. `'` não é  o mesmo que `\``

Answer (score 3):

Você estava usando o [Template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) de ***maneira errada*** o correto para concatenar é dentro da `string` colocar o cifrão entre colchetes e a variável, exemplo:  `a soma dos valores é : ${s}`

```js
var n1 = Number.parseInt(window.prompt(`digite um número: `))
var n2 = Number.parseInt(window.prompt(`digite outro número:`))
var s = n1 + n2
window.alert(`a soma dos valores é : ${s}`);
```

esse [Template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) faz parte da `ES6/ES2015` não sendo assim compatíveis com todos os navegadores (***os antigos***).

Para fazer de uma maneira ideal siga o exemplo abaixo:

```js
var n1 = Number.parseInt(window.prompt('digite um número: '))
var n2 = Number.parseInt(window.prompt('digite outro número: '))
var s = n1 + n2
window.alert('a soma dos valores é : ' + s);
```

sendo assim compatível com os navegadores.